# How to call a member function of a tuple struct with private fields

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get the string value returned by `__description(&self)` of `TryFromIntError`:

```
use std::num::TryFromIntError;

fn main() {
    let e: TryFromIntError = TryFromIntError();
    println!("{}", e);
}
```

And I get `error[E0423]: cannot initialize a tuple struct which contains private fields` because of its visibility:

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TryFromIntError(pub(crate) ());

impl TryFromIntError {
    #[unstable(
        feature = "int_error_internals",
        reason = "available through Error trait and this method should \
                  not be exposed publicly",
        issue = "none"
    )]
    #[doc(hidden)]
    pub fn __description(&self) -> &str {
        "out of range integral type conversion attempted"
    }
}
```

But how can I get this string value then?
Basically, I'd like to programmatically get `"out of range integral type conversion attempted"` instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: There are easy ways to construct a `TryFromIntError` if that's what you're worried about. For instance, `i8::try_from(999 as i16).unwrap_err()`. But based on the private field, the `unstable(...)`, and the `doc(hidden)`, it seems the authors of this struct don't *want* you getting or relying on direct access to that function. So even if you *do* get it and write a test or something that depends on it, that test will fail next time Rust updates this function, and it won't count as a breaking change since you were poking around places you weren't supposed to.

Comment: As asked, there is no answer to your question besides "you can't"

Comment: Could you give more context why you want to access the description of an error that has not occurred yet? Is this for unit testing?